# Web API return either JSON or XML based on user request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want my web service to return either JSON or XML based on which the user requests. If user A requests XML, I need the service to return XML, and if user B requests JSON, it must return JSON. How can I achieve this?

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its depend on what type of request you send and what type of response you want to receive
e.g. json requst using ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:49493/api/Values",
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify([name, address, dob]), //{ Name: name, 
                                          // Address: address, DOB: dob },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) { },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
```

Comment: thanks buddy for u r time. one more thing if we want to do in api level is there any option i.e if user mentioned in url itself can i diffrentiate other than content type

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do anything special.
Web Api will return your response base on your content-type request header.

That means that if your header will say 'application\json', the web-api will return you a json.
The same occurs for XML.

[Further Info](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)